# Dash Data table download to excel

Tags: python, plotly-dash

I am currently using the below script to download the data table from the dash which i created. The download is working fine however when i hosted the Dash locally and when i try to click the download button through another system, the file is being downloaded at the host computer and not at user computer. I apologize if my question seems silly as i am very new to Dash & python.

```py
html.Button(id="save-button", n_clicks=0, children="Save"),
html.Div(id="output-1", children="Press button to save data at your desktop")


@app.callback(
    Output("output-1", "children"),
    [Input("save-button", "n_clicks")],
    [State("table", "data")])
def selected_data_to_csv(nclicks, table1):
    if nclicks == 0:
        raise dash.PreventUpdate
    else:
        df = pd.DataFrame(table1).to_csv(
            'C:\\Users\\'+loggedin_user + '\\Desktop\\Open_Queue_Dump.csv', index=False)
    return "Data Submitted"
```

Answer (score 8):

Check out the [dash-extensions package](https://pypi.org/project/dash-extensions/), helped me with my app. It has this component called "Download". When you return something to it, the user is prompted to download it. So your code could look something like this:

```py
import io
import dash
import dash_html_components as html
from dash.dependencies import Input, Output, State
from dash.exceptions import PreventUpdate
from dash_extensions import Download
import dash_table
from flask import Flask
import pandas as pd

server = Flask(__name__)
app = dash.Dash(server=server)

df = pd.read_csv('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/plotly/datasets/master/solar.csv')

app.layout = html.Div(
                [
                    Download(id="download"),
                    html.Button("Save",
                                id="save-button"),
                    html.Div("Press button to save data at your desktop",
                             id="output-1"),
                    dash_table.DataTable(
                        id='table',
                        columns=[{"name": i, "id": i} for i in df.columns],
                        data=df.to_dict('records'),
                    )
                ]
            )


@app.callback(
Output("download", "data"),
Input("save-button", "n_clicks"),
State("table", "data"))
def download_as_csv(n_clicks, table_data):
    df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(table_data)
    if not n_clicks:
      raise PreventUpdate
    download_buffer = io.StringIO()
    df.to_csv(download_buffer, index=False)
    download_buffer.seek(0)
    return dict(content=download_buffer.getvalue(), filename="some_filename.csv")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server()
```

Comment: Note that the Download component has been migrated to dash.dcc.Download.  It still exists in dash_extensions. - Marie

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming that you are trying to export to a `csv` file from the snippet you shared. If that's the case, I've answered it in this [other thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64129482/13837091) that exporting is official supported in`dash_table`. I shared the following snippet:

```py
import dash_table
table = dash_table.DataTable(
    id="table",
    columns=[{"name": i, "id": i} for i in df.columns],
    data=df.to_dict("records"),
    export_format="csv",  # This will make an export button appear
)
```

However, the export format could also be in `xlsx`, as specified in [the docs](https://dash.plotly.com/datatable/reference). Then you would get the following code instead:

```py
import dash_table
table = dash_table.DataTable(
    id="table",
    columns=[{"name": i, "id": i} for i in df.columns],
    data=df.to_dict("records"),
    export_format="xlsx",  # This will make an export button appear
)
```

`table` simply refers to the component. Once defined you can use it in your code:

```py
table = ...

app = dash.Dash(__name__)
server = app.server

app.layout = html.Div([
    html.P("Here's my table:"),
    table
])

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run_server(debug=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes you are triggering a download to the server's C drive. Please see the below sample code taken from [here](https://community.plotly.com/t/download-raw-data/4700/8) which should do what you want:

```
import dash
import dash_core_components as dcc
import dash_html_components as html
import pandas as pd
import urllib

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'a': [1, 2, 3, 4],
    'b': [2, 1, 5, 6],
    'c': ['x', 'x', 'y', 'y']
})


def generate_table(dataframe, max_rows=10):
    return html.Table(
        # Header
        [html.Tr([html.Th(col) for col in dataframe.columns])] +

        # Body
        [html.Tr([
            html.Td(dataframe.iloc[i][col]) for col in dataframe.columns
        ]) for i in range(min(len(dataframe), max_rows))]
    )


app = dash.Dash(__name__)
app.css.append_css({"external_url": "https://codepen.io/chriddyp/pen/bWLwgP.css"})
app.layout = html.Div([
    html.Label('Filter'),

    dcc.Dropdown(
        id='field-dropdown',
        options=[
            {'label': i, 'value': i} for i in
            (['all'] + list(df['c'].unique()))],
        value='all'
    ),
    html.Div(id='table'),
    html.A(
        'Download Data',
        id='download-link',
        download="rawdata.csv",
        href="",
        target="_blank"
    )
])


def filter_data(value):
    if value == 'all':
        return df
    else:
        return df[df['c'] == value]


@app.callback(
    dash.dependencies.Output('table', 'children'),
    [dash.dependencies.Input('field-dropdown', 'value')])
def update_table(filter_value):
    dff = filter_data(filter_value)
    return generate_table(dff)


@app.callback(
    dash.dependencies.Output('download-link', 'href'),
    [dash.dependencies.Input('field-dropdown', 'value')])
def update_download_link(filter_value):
    dff = filter_data(filter_value)
    csv_string = dff.to_csv(index=False, encoding='utf-8')
    csv_string = "data:text/csv;charset=utf-8," + urllib.quote(csv_string)
    return csv_string


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(debug=True)
```

Comment: Its still downloading to the server folder instead of user folder. Any advise.

Comment: Are you clicking on the download link?

Comment: yes i do. Its still saving at server folder instead of users. Kindly advise how to proceed. I am new to python & Dash and it is difficult to find out where i went wrong.